# Android emulator in Eclipse luna

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I have created a hybrid project in Eclipse Luna and I try to run it using Android emulator. I have installed Android SDK. However it gives me back this message.

```
"Launching FirstApp(Android Emulator)" has encountered a problem.
Error generating the native android project.

Details

Error generating the native android project
The system is not able to find disc predetermined path
```

I think I have inserted the path for Android SDK folder right. What can I do?

Comment: Is this a message from the ADB or from the compiler? I just have a slight idea that ADB might not have detected your project properly.

Comment: I think it is from compiler because I make right click to project file Run as and I select the Android Emulator. More strange for me it that the emulator is openning without my project.

Comment: By "hybrid" do you mean THyM or some other toolset?

Comment: Yes apache cordova through jboss using this http://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2014/november/article3.php

Comment: Sorry, it is out of my field of knowledge. I edited the question tags reflect what you are asking. There is a big difference between cordova and Android.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I though it was only the android emulator configuration path.

Comment: To narrow your problem down, you could try to start a simple native Android project (Just an hello world or empty app). If that runs those configurations are correct.